# Understanding the proof of $a\equiv b\pmod{n}\implies r_n(a)=r_n(b)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I have seen a proof of the following problem, but I don't fully understand the proof.

> Prove that $$a\equiv b\pmod{n}\implies r_n(a)=r_n(b),$$ where $r_n(h)$ means the remainder of $h$ in the division by $n$.

**Proof**.
By the division algorithm, $a=qn+r_a$ and $b=cn+r_b$. Then $$a-b=qn+r_a-cn-r_b=(q-c)n+(r_a-r_b).$$ By hypothesis $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ i.e. $n\mid a-b$, so it must be $r_a-r_b=0$ i.e. $r_a=r_b$. $\square$

---

My **doubt** is in the last part: "so it must be $r_a-r_b=0$".

**Question** (in red):
If $n\mid a-b$ (I understand this) then there exists a $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $a-b=kn$. Hence we would have: $$a-b=\;\;\;\underbrace{kn=(q-c)n}_{\color{red}{\text{How can be equal $k$ and $q-c$?}}}+(r_a-r_b).$$

Comment: That's because $r_a=r_b$.

Comment: what's the sticking point ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I am not seeing why $n\mid a-b\implies r_a-r_b=0$.

Comment: @Bernard that's what we need to prove... Please look at the comment above (sorry for this misunderstandings).

Comment: $r_a\color{red}-rb=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that both $r_a$ and $r_b$ belong to $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Therefore,$$r_a-r_b\in\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots,\pm(n-1)\}.$$But the only element of this set which is a multiple of $n$ is $0$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupe FAQs

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $k$ is not $q-c$ then $(k-(q-c))n=r_a-r_b$ hence $n$ divides $r_a-r_b$ but what does the division algorithm tells you about them?

Comment: This is a great help! I don't know what the division algorithm tells me. If $k\neq q-c$ then $n\mid r_a-r_b$, then..?

Comment: the algorithm tells you that $0\leq r_a,r_b<n$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Then we have $0\leq r_a<n$ and $0\leq r_b<n$. What is the next step?

Comment: Then we have $0-0\leq r_a-r_b<n-n=0\implies r_a-r_b=0$ right?

Comment: Nop, you can not subtract like that, but then how can you get a number greater or equal than $n$ by subtracting them??

Comment: Why do we need to find a number greater or equal than $n$?